# Guava Resources getResource() not working the first time

Tags: java, classpath, classloader, guava, urlclassloader

I am observing a peculiar behavior in my code.
I have this code:

```
String propsPath = Resources.getResource(
                    "xyz.properties").getPath();
```

And I always get this error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: resource xyz.properties not found.

the first time I call the method which is using the above block of code. On consequent calls the method works fine and is able to locate the resource properly. Upon inspecting the `getResource` code I can see

```
public static URL getResource(String resourceName) {
    URL url = Resources.class.getClassLoader().getResource(resourceName);
    checkArgument(url != null, "resource %s not found.", resourceName);
    return url;
  }
```

Upon debugging sure enough the `url` its getting the first time is `null`. How does the same piece of code work consequently?

I found this in the javadoc of `getClassLoader`

> Returns the class loader for the class. Some implementations may use
>   null to represent the bootstrap class loader. This method will return
>   null in such implementations if this class was loaded by the bootstrap
>   class loader.

Can someone explain me what is the `bootstrap class loader`? And is my code using the same the first time but some other class loader the next time? Or is it some entirely other issue?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try a newer version of Guava. I don't know if it'll fix your problem, but a while back we made a change to use `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` if it exists rather than using `Resources.class.getClassLoader()`.

Also, note that `getClassLoader()` isn't returning `null`... you'd get a `NullPointerException` if it were. `getResource("xyz.properties")` is returning `null`, which just means that it couldn't find that resource. I'm not sure why it would work on subsequent calls but not the first... that's strange.

Comment: Hi Colin, can you tell me what led the Guava team to make this change? And how are the 2 approaches different?

Comment: @AbhiroopSarkar: It's mostly because it's better in situations where there are multiple classloaders; you probably want a resource from the same classloader that's loading _your_ classes, because that's probably where your resources are as well. If Guava is loaded on a separate classloader, `Resources.class.getClassLoader()` wouldn't be able to find your resource. The context classloader is more likely to be the one that loaded your code.

Comment: This doesnt seem to fix. I am using guava 15 now which has this code `ClassLoader loader = Objects.firstNonNull(
        Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(),
        Resources.class.getClassLoader());
    URL url = loader.getResource(resourceName);
    checkArgument(url != null, "resource %s not found.", resourceName);
    return url;`